# How to auto-check Google approved scopes on OAuth page?

Tags: django, google-api, google-oauth

I've been fully verified for the Google Calendar API as shown in the image below...

[image: shows that scope is approved]

...but when users hit my OAuth consent screen on the webflow, the box is unchecked by default on the calendar as shown in the following image...

[image: calendar scope unchecked by default]

Is there any way to ensure that the box is checked by default?

I'm using Django as my framework with the code below for the auth flow:

```
    flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.Flow.from_client_secrets_file(
    env('GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET'),
    scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email', 'openid']
    )
    
flow.redirect_uri = env('GOOGLE_FLOW_REDIRECT_URI')

authorization_url, state = flow.authorization_url(
access_type='offline',
prompt='consent',
include_granted_scopes='true'
)
```

Comment: To make this matter a bit more odd, if I click "Continue" without checking the calendar box, then my service will fail, but then if I hit "Back" on the browser it will show the Calendar access box as being checked...I have a feeling this has something to do with the incremental authorization protocol, but even if I mess with the "include_granted_scopes" it doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here, quite erratic it works differnt on others oauth, looks their a bug to us, it should ask for every permission and then confirm with the actuall screen with unchecked marks.